# What can I be? $~~$

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Different people regards me differently 
>  
>   Though I meant little importance and 
>   I am intended primarily as entertainment 
>   Yet there is a house made just for me 
>   I am also needed by plants and 
>   I am needed by those who read this 
>   I can be bright but I can also be dull and pale

**What can I be?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is it:

> ***Light***?

Different people regards me differently

> Light-weight, light-hearted, etc.

Though I meant little importance and

> Light matters?!?

I am intended primarily as entertainment

> Lightbulb, Light-music,etc.

Yet there is a house made just for me

> Lighthouse

I am also needed by plants and

> Plants require light for photosynthesis and stuff...

I am needed by those who read this

> We need light to read

I can be bright but I can also be dull and pale

> Bright light / Low light

Comment: Lightbulbs are entertaining to you?

Comment: I'd understand LED's as entertainment for TV's ect, but not light bulbs :P

Comment: Ok, I seriously dunno what mindset I was in when I felt light bulbs were entertainment material... Shows when you are bored, anything is entertaining! :P

Comment: Congratulation, the answer is correct! 
but the explanation for the last one is a bit off. 
I was thinking that the word light can be an adjective to describe bright (E.g.: Her house is light and airy) or dull and pale (E.g.:Light purple).

Comment: I don't know how lightbulbs is entertaining but I agree with the light music

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> the color green?

Different people regards me differently

> Colorblind people will see green differently

Though I meant little importance and

> Not sure about this one

I am intended primarily as entertainment

> Green screens?

Yet there is a house made just for me

> Greenhouse

I am also needed by plants and

> Chlorophyll

I am needed by those who read this

> Could mean vegetables, or maybe money (USD)

I can be bright but I can also be dull and pale

> Different shades of green

Comment: Wow. Thank you for your fascinating idea and creativity. I never thought of it that way but this is really out of the box. XD